# about python 2.7 encoding : i am really confused

Tags: python, python-2.7, encoding, kivy

i coded by python 3.6 and i recently changed python version 3.6 to 2.7(because i want convert this file to IOS application but only 2.7version can do it so far.)

here is problem. i tested this code in python3.6 and there is no problem.
but i run this in 2.7..encoding problem was appear.

here is my .py file

```
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import kivy
kivy.require('1.10.0')
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.animation import Animation
from kivy.clock import Clock
#from kivy.config import Config #윈도우크기고정
#Config.set('graphics', 'resizable', 0)
from kivy.core.window import Window #윈도우크기설정
Window.size = (486, 650) 

class Loading_Screen(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Loading_Screen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        Clock.schedule_once(self.callNext, 2) 

    def callNext(self,dt): 
        self.manager.current = 'Before_First_Screen'

class Load_BusInfo():
    pass

class Before_First_Screen(Screen):
    pass

class First_Screen(Screen):
    pass

class Test_Screen(Screen):
    pass

###################목적지_역명#####################

class DTN_TECHNOPARK(Screen): 
    pass

class DTN_BITZONE(Screen): 
    pass

class DTN_INUSTATION(Screen): 
    pass

class Bus_Information(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Bus_Information, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        with open('C:/Users/mg/Desktop/Tubuc/station/동막역(1번출구)ICB164000039.txt') as businfo:
            Businfo= [] 
            nolinenum=businfo.readline()
            while nolinenum!='': 
                Businfo.append(nolinenum)
                leftstations = (businfo.readline().rstrip('\n') + ' 정거장'.rstrip('\n'))
                lefttime = (businfo.readline().rstrip('\n') + ' 초'.rstrip('\n'))
                nolinenum = businfo.readline().rstrip('\n')
                Businfo.append(leftstations)
                Businfo.append(lefttime)
            self.businfolist = Businfo
            self.lenbil = int(len(Businfo))
            self.numberoflist = int(len(Businfo)/3)

class ScreenManagement(ScreenManager):
    pass

presentation = Builder.load_file("testmain.kv")

class TubucApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return presentation

TubucApp().run()
```

and this is error contents.

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:\Users\mg\Desktop\TubucTest\testtubuc.py", line 71, in <module>
     presentation = Builder.load_file("testmain.kv")
   File "C:\Users\mg\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 301, in load_file
     return self.load_string(data, **kwargs)
   File "C:\Users\mg\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 400, in load_string
     self._apply_rule(widget, parser.root, parser.root)
   File "C:\Users\mg\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 582, in _apply_rule
     child = cls(__no_builder=True)
   File "C:\Users\mg\Desktop\TubucTest\testtubuc.py", line 54, in __init__
     with open('C:/Users/mg/Desktop/Tubuc/station/동막역(1번출구)ICB164000039.txt') as businfo:
 IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:/Users/mg/Desktop/Tubuc/station/\xeb\x8f\x99\xeb\xa7\x89\xec\x97\xad(1\xeb\xb2\x88\xec\xb6\x9c\xea\xb5\xac)ICB164000039.txt'
```

### 동막역(1번출구) is seen as \xeb\x8f\x99\xeb\xa7\x89\xec\x97\xad(1\xeb\xb2\x88\xec\xb6\x9c\xea\xb5\xac) on the last line.

How can i fix this? thank you for reading.

Comment: change `'C:/Users/mg/Desktop/Tubuc/station/동막역(1번출구)ICB164000039.txt'` to `u'C:/Users/mg/Desktop/Tubuc/station/동막역(1번출구)ICB164000039.txt'`

Comment: @AzatIbrakov already tried it. but still similar error is occuring.  IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: u'C:/Users/mg/Desktop/Tubuc/station/\ub3d9\ub9c9\uc5ed(1\ubc88\ucd9c\uad6c)ICB164000039.txt'

Comment: this is a different error, try `import os; print(os.path.exists(u'C:/Users/mg/Desktop/Tubuc/station/동막역(1번출구)ICB164000039.txt'))` and check if the output is `True`

Comment: @AzatIbrakov i am sry to bother you but the output is False.

Comment: ahh never mind! i missspelled the path!! thank you!!